# The reverse pizza problem .

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, circles

The pizza problem is a fairly well-known problem which sounds like this :

> You have a circular pizza and you need to cut it such that you and your friend would both receive half of the pizza . Because you're bored you decide not to cut through the center but rather through an arbitrary point on the pizza .You make $n$ cuts through the pizza with angles of $\frac{\pi}{n}$ between them .Each one of you takes one slice alternatively in a clock-wise way. Prove that this slicing is fair for $n \neq 2$ even  but for $n$ odd or $n=2$ it isn't  .

After seeing the problem I tried it for other pizza shapes also . I observed that the square quickly failed (for two cuts ) and this made me realize that the pizza should be quite 'round'.

Based on this I conjectured the following :

> Consider a closed convex set as the 'shape' of the pizza .Also choose $n$ a fixed positive integer .Take an arbitrary point on the pizza and then make $n$ cuts through it with angles $\frac{\pi}{n}$ between them . The friends take the slices alternatively in a clock-wise way. Assume that the friends always get the same amount of pizza for every point on the pizza and any first cut . Prove that the pizza must be a circle .

I realize that maybe this problem (with a convex set) might be too hard so I would be quite happy with any partial results possible (for polygons , triangles , ... I am sure these are a lot simpler )

Thanks for everyone who could help me with this problem . All your help is greatly appreciated .

**EDIT** I will add some partial results I have found :

$1)$If $n=1$ then it's not possible for any shape .

This should be obvious . Draw a point close enough through the boundary and then a line through it that cuts a small piece of pizza .

$2)$ If $n=2$ and the pizza is a convex polygon with at least one acute angle (or right angle )then it's not possible .

This isn't hard either . Draw a point close enough to the vertex with the acute angle (or right angle) . Draw a cut parallel with one of the sides of the angle and the other cut perpendicular to it . There will be one very big slice one very small slice and two other slices . Now make the point closer and closer to the vertex until the big slice is big enough . This slicing is not fair .

Comment: The pizza problem requires additional constraints on $n$ than what you've stated. For example, even if you have a circular pizza, you can have an unfair slicing with 2 cuts (just pick a point close to the circumference of the pizza, and one person will get way more pizza).

Comment: @Batman Thanks for the observation. Can you tell me what is the condition I missed ?

Comment: You'd have to look it up or prove it, but its something like you need at least 8 cuts and the number of cuts needs to be divisible by 4 to guarantee fairness.

Comment: @Batman Yes you're right . Here's the Wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_theorem